# Generating Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $b>a+n$ for integer $n$, and $a+b$ is minimum

Tags: pythagorean-triples

> I'm trying to generate a Pythagorean triple, that is, $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$ that
> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
> under the condition that $b > a + n$, $n \in \mathbb N$ and $a+b$ is minimum.

I tried expanding the forumula or trying to use the Euclid's formula but I don't know how to add the constraint.

Comment: Must the triple be primitive ?

Comment: @Peter No, it's not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between legs of a  [primitive] Pythagorean triple is always
$\quad P=p_1^a p_2^b p_3^c \cdots\quad$
the product "P" of one-or-more [non-negative] "powers" of primes "p" where
$\quad P\equiv p_n^x\equiv\pm1\pmod8.\quad $
Under
$200,$ $$\space  P\in \bigg\{1,\space 7,\space  17,\space  23,\space  31,\space  41,\space  47,\space  \big(7^2\big),\space  71,\space  73,\space  79,\space  89,\space  97,\space  \big(7\times 17\big),\\ 
  127,
 137,\space 151,\space \big (7\times23\big),
\space  167,\space  191,\space 199
\bigg\}$$
The statement of this question
$\mid B-A\mid >n$ would be better phrased as
$\mid B-A\mid \le P\space$ as we will see below.

For $P=1$. there are three formulas, two of which generates the "pell" number pairs
$\big(2,5,12,29,70,\cdots\big)$
needed to feed Euclid's formula here shown as
$\quad A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2.\quad$  For example
$$F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\quad
F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\quad
F(12,5)=(119,120,169)$$

For $P>1,\quad$ one formula may be generalized to $\quad m=k+\sqrt{2k^2\pm P}\quad
1\le k \le\big\lfloor \sqrt{P}\space\big\rfloor
\quad$
which generates  at least $2^x$ series  of pell-like numbers where $x$ is the sum of powers of $p_n.\quad$ Any $k$-value in range which yields an integer is the first-k
$\space (k_1)\space$
of such a series. For $P=7,\space$ this means there are $2^1$= $2$ series:
$\space P=7\implies  k_1\in\{1.2\}.$

\begin{align*}
1+\sqrt{2+7}=4\quad  &  F(4,1)=(15,8,17)\\
 4+\sqrt{32-7}=9\quad  &   F(9,4)=(65,72,97)\\
9 +\sqrt{162+7}=22\quad  &  F(22,9)=(403,396,565)\\
 22 +\sqrt{968-7}=53\quad  &  F(53,22)=(2325,2332,3293)\\
 \vdots\\ 
\text{ and }\\ \\
 2+\sqrt{8-7}=3\quad  &F(3,2)=(5,12,13)\\
   3 +\sqrt{18+7}=8\quad &F(8,3)=(55,48,73)\\
 8 +\sqrt{128-7}=19\quad &F(19,8)=(297,304,425)\\
    19 +\sqrt{722+7}=46\quad &F(46,19)=(1755,1748,2477)\\ \vdots
 \end{align*}

In this case, we have generated triples for $n>6.\quad$ For $n>7$, we would have to use the formula
$m=k+\sqrt{2k^2\pm 17},\space
1\le k \le\big\lfloor \sqrt{17}\space\big\rfloor
=4\quad$  to get $\space k_1\in\{2,3\}$

$$F(7,2)=(45,28,53)\quad 
F(16,7)=(207,224,305)\quad
F(39,16)=(1265,1248,1777))\quad\cdots\quad\\
F(4,3)=(7,24,25)\quad
F(11,4)=(105,88,137)\quad
F(26,11)=(555,572,797)\quad\cdots $$

For $P=49=7^2,\space k_1\in\{4,5,6,7\};\quad$
for $P=119=7\times17,\space  
k_1\in\{1,5,8,10\},\space$  etc.

Do note that, for half of all triples, $A>B. \quad$ This simply means
$\mid\space B-A\mid\space\equiv
\space\pm1\pmod8.\quad$
The generalized formula works for any $P>n.$

The smallest first triple in any of the
one-or-more series of triples generated contains the minimum for the criteria. For example, for $\quad n>6\longrightarrow (15,8,17),\space (5,12,13),\quad$
the minimum $A+B\space$ is $\space 5+12=17$.

A brief list of these minimum $B+A$ values for $n\le P$ is
\begin{equation}n(A,B,C)\longrightarrow B+A\\
1(3,4,5)\longrightarrow 7\\
7(5,12,13)\longrightarrow 17\\
17(7,24,25)\longrightarrow 31\\
23(35,12,37)\longrightarrow 47\\
31(9,40,41)\longrightarrow 49\\
41(77,36,85)\longrightarrow 113\\
47(63,16,65)\longrightarrow 79\\
49(11,60,61)\longrightarrow 71\\
\end{equation}